Flutter StreamBuilder cannot receive all data, or override listen event？
Dio post to server like this:
dio.post<ResponseBody>(
      'url',
      data: {...},
      options: Options(
          responseType: ResponseType.stream,
          headers: {
            "Authorization": TokenUtil.token,
            "Accept": "*/*"
          }
      )
    ).then((res) => {
      res.data?.stream
        .transform(unit8Transformer)
        .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
        .transform(const LineSplitter()).listen((event) {
        if (event.contains('data:')) {
          print('current Data：$event');
          _counterSink.add(event);
        }
      }, onDone: () => {
        setState(() {
          currentState = ConnectionState.done;
        })
      }),
    });

and StreamBuilder is:
StreamBuilder(stream: _counterStream, initialData: '', builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
  print('received Data：${snapshot.data}');
})

while print this: So I don't kown why sometimes cannot receive currentData, or even counterSink don't add it.
Refer Image
Please help me solve it. Thanks

It seems your response, content parameter, sometimes returns a list and sometimes a string.
This maybe cause a problem while mapping the response.
Implement onError method and print/log it. It should give you more information on whats wrong
